# How to add <script> tag using ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to declare a javascript function as described below:

```
render: function() {
  return (
          <div>
            <SomeReactClass somefunction="myFunction">
            <script>
              function myFunction(index, row) {
                return index;                       <<<< error in this line 
              }
            </script>
          </div>
          );
}
```

But, it does not compile: "Parse Error: Line 113: Unexpected token return"

How can I add  tag using ReactJS?

---

### UPDATE

I'm trying to use [bootstrap-table detail view](http://issues.wenzhixin.net.cn/bootstrap-table/#options/detail-view.html). The function is passed as parameter to the grid and it is used to render the row's detail. Also, see the [example's source code](https://github.com/wenzhixin/bootstrap-table-examples/blob/master/options/detail-view.html) for a better understanding.

When I try the way you're saying, it compiles, but does not work at all:

This is how it looks like (in example above):

[image]

This is what I'm getting with `<SomeReactClass somefunction={myFunction}>`

[image]

Comment: Why would you want to add a `<script>` element in the first place? (this should probably not throw an error, but it's an odd case anyway)

Comment: (I was wrong btw, the error is correct)

Comment: You may want to check this answer. [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48966464/add-raw-html-with-script-inside-gatsby-react-page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48966464/add-raw-html-with-script-inside-gatsby-react-page) It works for me. This should be a comment but I don't have enough reputation...

Answer (score 13):

I know this is old, but i stumbled upon this recently and here is the best solution i found (i'm using it for browser polyfills, but it works for any code):

```
render: function() {
  return (
     <div>
        <SomeReactClass somefunction="myFunction">
        <script
          dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html:
            `function myFunction(index, row) {return index;}`
          }}
        />
     </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 12):

Inside JSX, `{...}` denotes a JavaScript expression. `return index;` on its own is not a valid expression.

You have to explicitly create a string so that the `{...}` are not interpreted by JSX. Template literals may be the easiest solution:

```
<script>{`
    function myFunction(index, row) {
        return index;
    }
`}</script>
```

However, I have a hard time coming up with a reason why one would want to create a `<script>` dynamically.

---

What you should probably do is pass the function directly to the component:

```
function myFunction(index, row) {
    return index;
}

var Component = React.createElement({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
        <SomeReactClass somefunction={myFunction} />
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

But it's hard to tell without you explaining what you are really trying to achieve here.

Comment: Fix `SomeReactClass` to expect a function, not a string.

Comment: It looks like the underlying plugin expects a string attribute that corresponds to a function on the global scope https://github.com/wenzhixin/bootstrap-table/blob/master/src/bootstrap-table.js#L136. So if the OP wants to use an html attribute to initialize the bootstrap component he'll need to attach it attach it to window. Otherwise he can initialize the table manually.

Answer (score 1):

i think youre just looking for interpolation of your JS

```
function myFunction(index, row) {
  return index;    
}
render: function() {
  return (
    <div>
      <SomeReactClass somefunction={myFunction}>
    </div>
  );
}
```

to interpolate javascript in jsx utilize curly braces `{}`
https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#javascript-expressions

per your edit:
again, you need to be using the braces to interpolate your function. so inside of `SomeReactClass` you need to be doing something like this in the render function:

```
<div>{this.props.myFunction(index, row)}</div>
```

most notably, you need to not only interpolate the function, by you also need to be executing it.

Comment: That doesn't make a lot of sense. This would try to render a function as a child of a `<div>`.

Comment: updated. it would be helpful for us to see the code of your example `SomeReactClass` because it doesnt look like your executing it correctly. Id also suggest reading the docs to how to properly use jsx from the link i posted

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

```
function myFunction(index, row) {
  return index;    
}

render: function() {
 return (
      <div>
        <script
            dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ 
              __html:myFunction() 
        
            }}
        />
      </div>
      );
}
```