# add raw HTML with <script> inside Gatsby React page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

I am trying to add an external embed code to my Gatsby page.

I currently use

```
import React from 'react'
import Link from 'gatsby-link'


let test ="<script type='text/javascript'>
(function(d, s) {
    var useSSL = 'https:' == document.location.protocol;
    var js, where = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
    js = d.createElement(s);
    js.src = (useSSL ? 'https:' : 'http:') +  '//www.peopleperhour.com/hire/1002307300/1213788.js?width=300&height=135&orientation=vertical&theme=light&rnd='+parseInt(Math.random()*10000, 10);
    try { where.parentNode.insertBefore(js, where); } catch (e) { if (typeof console !== 'undefined' && console.log && e.stack) { console.log(e.stack); } }
}(document, 'script'));
</script>"

const ContactPage = () => (

    <div>
        <h1>ContactPage</h1>
        <div
            dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: test }}
          />
    </div>

)

export default ContactPage
```

which is full of syntax errors. Can you please point out a better way to include raw snippets in a react component?

Is there alternatively a place in Gatsby to add all additional scripts like custom scripts, Google Analytics, icon fonts, animate.js and anything else I may need?

Thank you for the help

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can inject external scripts (with no npm modules) to gatsby.js project in many ways. Prefer to use respective gatsby-plugin for "web-analytics" scripts.

Using `require()` :

- Create a file in your project `myScript.js` and paste the script content
- Add `const myExtScript = require('../pathToMyScript/myScript')`
  to a **statefull** component at the **Pages** folder inside `render()` and before `return()` if you want to execute that script **only at that page**(=page/component scope).

  ```js
  export default class Contact extends React.Component {  
    render() {  
     const myExtScript = require('../pathToMyScript/myScript')  
      return (
        ........       
                 )}
  ```
- If you want to execute script in the **global scope** (=in every page/ component):
  add it in `html.js`

  ```js
  <script dangerouslySetInnerHTML= {{ __html: ` 
      putYourSciptHereInBackticks `}} />`
  ```

  before closing the `</body>`. It is better to manipulate/monitor your global scope at this component because it has this specific purpose... to inject html to every page/route globally.
- Another way to inject at the **global scope** is with `require()` before the component declaration. *This will work but it's not a good practice, as your components shouldn't inject anything globally.*

  ```js
   const myExtScript = require('../pathToMyScript/myScript')  

     export default class Contact extends React.Component {  
      render() {  
        return (
        ........       
                 )}
  ```

P.S. Sorry if the answer is not edited properly. This my first answer at StackOverflow.

Comment: will you show some GitHub repo about these examples?

Comment: what is the script is using the online script instead of local file?
e.g: <script src="https://blah-blah/js/blah.js" />

Answer (score 11):

Use [React-Helmet](https://github.com/nfl/react-helmet)

First `import Helmet from 'react-helmet'`

Inside your `div` you can do like this

```js
<Helmet>
<script type='text/javascript'>
(function(d, s) {
    var useSSL = 'https:' == document.location.protocol;
    var js, where = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
    js = d.createElement(s);
    js.src = (useSSL ? 'https:' : 'http:') +  '//www.peopleperhour.com/hire/1002307300/1213788.js?width=300&height=135&orientation=vertical&theme=light&rnd='+parseInt(Math.random()*10000, 10);
    try { where.parentNode.insertBefore(js, where); } catch (e) { if (typeof console !== 'undefined' && console.log && e.stack) { console.log(e.stack); } }
}(document, 'script'));
</script>
</Helmet>
```

Comment: Thank you, but this produces the same syntax errors as my initial code. It cannot be transpiled

Comment: This is not really a solution to the problem, but a workaround I found was to inject custom scripts using Google Tag Manager. This won't be appropriate in all scenarios, but if you're injecting something like a tracking script it works great, and it helps to avoid littering your code with unmanaged scripts. I just used it to inject a MailChimp popup code on a Gatsby page and it worked great.

Comment: Do we have to use it in all the files of our whole project? Is there any smart work there to do with single included in the whole project?

Comment: @AaronNewton GTM doesnt work with the mailchimp script right? Not as far as i know.

Comment: @Logemann I haven't tried it recently, but you can inject any script onto the page with GTM. I've even used it to replace content when I was in a jam. https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/6107167?hl=en

Answer (score 2):

Apparently using a multiline JS syntax did the trick, as in

```
let test = "<script type='text/javascript'>\
(function(d, s) {\
    var useSSL = 'https:' == document.location.protocol;\
    var js, where = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],\
    js = d.createElement(s);\
    js.src = (useSSL ? 'https:' : 'http:') +  '//www.peopleperhour.com/hire/1002307300/1213788.js?width=300&height=135&orientation=vertical&theme=light&rnd='+parseInt(Math.random()*10000, 10);\
    try { where.parentNode.insertBefore(js, where); } catch (e) { if (typeof console !== 'undefined' && console.log && e.stack) { console.log(e.stack); } }\
}(document, 'script'));\
</script><div id='pph-hireme'></div>"
```

alternatively, you can do

```
let test2 = `
<script type='text/javascript'>
(function(d, s) {
    var useSSL = 'https:' == document.location.protocol;
    var js, where = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
    js = d.createElement(s);
    js.src = (useSSL ? 'https:' : 'http:') +  '//www.peopleperhour.com/hire/1002307300/1213788.js?width=300&height=135&orientation=vertical&theme=light&rnd='+parseInt(Math.random()*10000, 10);\
    try { where.parentNode.insertBefore(js, where); } catch (e) { if (typeof console !== 'undefined' && console.log && e.stack) { console.log(e.stack); } }\
}(document, 'script'));
</script><div id='pph-hireme'></div>
`
```

Any more comments are welcome

Answer (score 2):

One way - perhaps the preferred way - is using the SSR file.

From the [docs](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/api-files-gatsby-ssr/):

> The file gatsby-ssr.js lets you alter the content of static HTML files
> as they are being Server-Side Rendered (SSR) by Gatsby and Node.js. To
> use the Gatsby SSR APIs, create a file called gatsby-ssr.js in the
> root of your site. Export any of the APIs you wish to use in this
> file.

A tutorial on how to do that is [here](https://isamrish.com/how-to-add-3rd-party-script-in-your-gatsby-website/).

It uses the `setHeadComponents` method to inject into html.js:

```
setHeadComponents
```

It takes an array of components as its first argument which will be added to head components during building time and which will be passed to html.js.

Answer (score 0):

There is another way, which is creating a React's effects:

```
import { useEffect } from 'react'

const useGoogleAnalytics = () => {

    useEffect(() => {
        // GA Snippet
    }, [])

    return null
}
```

And then you can use `useGoogleAnalytics()` in the page components you want to include.

The main advantage of this are:

- You get transpilation of the code
- It's way easier to maintain for more complex code than inside a template literal.

For simple scripts like Google Analytics I'd go for a template literal, but for custom and subject-to-change snippet I'd prefer an effect. As long as you *don't abuse* of those, It should not impact performance nor create overhead.

Does anyone see other disadvantages with this other method?