# Load Google Place API in Gatsbyjs (Reactjs) project

Tags: reactjs, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api, gatsby

I am trying to use the AutoComplete address service from Google Place API.

Found this library:
https://github.com/kenny-hibino/react-places-autocomplete#load-google-library

It asks for loading the library in my project:
https://github.com/kenny-hibino/react-places-autocomplete#getting-started

I would do it in the public/index.html if it's pure Reactjs project. However, the public/index.html in Gatsbyjs project will be deleted and re-generated every time when running:

```
Gatsby develop
```

command line.

How can I use the Google Place API in my Gatsbyjs project?

### Update

I have tried 2 ways to achieve this.

1. Use React-Helmet in /layouts/index.js , here is how it looks like:

   ```
       <Helmet>
         <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key={API}&libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete" async defer></script>
       </Helmet>
   ```

   [image]
2. Put the script reference in the /public/index.html, which looks like this:

   ```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>

   <head>
       <meta charSet="utf-8" />
       <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge" />
       <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no" />
       <title data-react-helmet="true"></title>
       <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
       <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key={API_KEY}&libraries=places" async defer ></script>
   </head>

   <body>
       <div id="___gatsby"></div>
       <script src="/commons.js"></script>
   </body>

   </html>
   ```

For the 1st solution, every time after I refresh my page, the project throws an error asking for loading the Google JavaScript Map API.

For the 2nd solution, every time after I re-start the Gatsby by the command line: `gatsby develop`

it re-generates the index.html which flushes away my JavaScript reference in it.

Comment: `key=API` what is this?

Comment: @MrUpsidown that's just a placeholder to not reveal my real api key.

Comment: why down vote? Happy to learn

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that allows to reproduce the issue and share the exact errors you see in your console.

Comment: @MrUpsidown sure, will update the question. But not real API key will be included :)

Comment: hi @MrUpsidown , updated. Hopefully it makes sense to you. thanks

Comment: Sorry I don't know react/gatsby/helmet... Did you try this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/48987164/1238965 + I saw your question on github, probably someone will reply there.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You shouldn't modify any files in the `public` forlder with **GatsbyJS**.

Instead, I recommend you to [customize your `html.js` file](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/custom-html/#custom-html).

To do so, first run:

```
cp .cache/default-html.js src/html.js
```

You should have the `html.js` file in **/src/html.js**.

Now you can put your `<script>` tag within the `<head>`.

Comment: exactly, I did it in this way and it solved my problem~! THanks

Comment: @Franva I still can't get this to work. Did you do anything else that's not noted here?

Comment: I figured out I needed to use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` but then had other issues and so in the end I just went with `google-maps-react` package. Thanks tho.

Answer (score 8):

### Update Feb 24, 2020

Here's a more modern implementation using React hooks with some performance optimizations based on `React.memo` and a custom `shouldUpdate` function. See [this blog post](https://janosh.io/blog/google-maps+react-hooks) for details.

```js
import { functions, isEqual, omit } from 'lodash'
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react'

function Map({ options, onMount, className, onMountProps }) {
  const ref = useRef()
  const [map, setMap] = useState()

  useEffect(() => {
    // The Map constructor modifies its options object in place by adding
    // a mapTypeId with default value 'roadmap'. This confuses shouldNotUpdate.
    // { ...options } prevents this by passing in a copy.
    const onLoad = () =>
      setMap(new window.google.maps.Map(ref.current, { ...options }))
    if (!window.google) {
      const script = document.createElement(`script`)
      script.src = `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=` + YOUR_API_KEY
      document.head.append(script)
      script.addEventListener(`load`, onLoad)
      return () => script.removeEventListener(`load`, onLoad)
    } else onLoad()
  }, [options])

  if (map && typeof onMount === `function`) onMount(map, onMountProps)

  return (
    <div
      style={{ height: `60vh`, margin: ` 1em 0`, borderRadius: ` 0.5em` }}
      {...{ ref, className }}
    />
  )
}

function shouldNotUpdate(props, nextProps) {
  const [funcs, nextFuncs] = [functions(props), functions(nextProps)]
  const noPropChange = isEqual(omit(props, funcs), omit(nextProps, nextFuncs))
  const noFuncChange =
    funcs.length === nextFuncs.length &&
    funcs.every(fn => props[fn].toString() === nextProps[fn].toString())
  return noPropChange && noFuncChange
}

export default React.memo(Map, shouldNotUpdate)

Map.defaultProps = {
  options: {
    center: { lat: 48, lng: 8 },
    zoom: 5,
  },
}
```

### Old Answer

#### Using html.js

Modifying `src/html.js` like so (as Nenu suggests) is one option.

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'

export default class HTML extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <html {...this.props.htmlAttributes}>
        <head>
          <meta charSet="utf-8" />
          <meta httpEquiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge" />
          <meta
            name="viewport"
            content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no"
          />
          {this.props.headComponents}
        </head>
        <body {...this.props.bodyAttributes}>
          {this.props.preBodyComponents}
          <div
            key={`body`}
            id="___gatsby"
            dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: this.props.body }}
          />
          {this.props.postBodyComponents}
          // MODIFICATION // ===================
          <script
            src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY"
            async
            defer
          />
          // ===================
        </body>
      </html>
    )
  }
}

HTML.propTypes = {
  htmlAttributes: PropTypes.object,
  headComponents: PropTypes.array,
  bodyAttributes: PropTypes.object,
  preBodyComponents: PropTypes.array,
  body: PropTypes.string,
  postBodyComponents: PropTypes.array,
}
```

Then you can access the Google Maps API anywhere in your project from `window.google.maps.(Map|Marker|etc.)`.

#### The React way

To me that felt a little anachronistic, though. If you want a reusable React component that you can import into any page or template as `import Map from './Map'`, I suggest this instead. (Hint: See update below for equivalent function component.)

```js
// src/components/Map.js
import React, { Component } from 'react'

export default class Map extends Component {
  onLoad = () => {
    const map = new window.google.maps.Map(
      document.getElementById(this.props.id),
      this.props.options
    )
    this.props.onMount(map)
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    if (!window.google) {
      const script = document.createElement('script')
      script.type = 'text/javascript'
      script.src = `https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY`
      const headScript = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]
      headScript.parentNode.insertBefore(script, headScript)
      script.addEventListener('load', () => {
        this.onLoad()
      })
    } else {
      this.onLoad()
    }
  }

  render() {
    return <div style={{ height: `50vh` }} id={this.props.id} />
  }
}
```

Use it like so:

```js
// src/pages/contact.js
import React from 'react'

import Map from '../components/Map'

const center = { lat: 50, lng: 10 }
const mapProps = {
  options: {
    center,
    zoom: 8,
  },
  onMount: map => {
    new window.google.maps.Marker({
      position: center,
      map,
      title: 'Europe',
    })
  },
}

export default function Contact() {
  return (
    <>
      <h1>Contact</h1>
      <Map id="contactMap" {...mapProps} />
    </>
  )
}
```

Comment: I like your approach, will try it later. thanks for sharing

Answer (score 0):

What woked for me was to create a gatsby-ssr.js file in the root of my project, and then include the script there, like this:

```
import React from "react"

export function onRenderBody({ setHeadComponents }) {
  setHeadComponents([
    <script
      key="abc"
      type="text/javascript"
      src={`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=${process.env.GATSBY_API_KEY}&libraries=places`}
    />,
  ])
}
```

Don't forget to include `GATSBY_API_KEY` or whatever you want to call it in your .env.development and .env.production files:

```
GATSBY_API_KEY=...
```