# Proper way to include a .js file in gatsby which executes its code on all the pages

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

**Premise** 
I have a static site which I'm converting into a [gatsby](https://gatsby.org) one. I've used jQuery to do certain DOM manipulation and other triggers like toggling the mobile menu and handling cookies. I want to include this file, `main.js` in such a way that the JavaScript inside of it gets executed on all the pages.

I've installed jQuery using npm and included it in `layout.js` using
`import $ from "jquery"`

I'm not able to achieve the above in a reliable way. Following are the methods that I've tried without any success.

**Method 1** 
Placed the entire code inside of `onInitialClientRender` in `gatsby-browser.js`

**Method 2** 
Copied `html.js` in the `src` folder and added the file via the `script` tag.

**Method 3** 
Followed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49898863/2427237) and placed the entire code inside of

```
<script dangerouslySetInnerHTML= {{ __html: `putYourSciptHereInBackticks `}} />
```

**Method 4** 
Followed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54844686/2427237) and tried to include the file using `react-helmet`. The code does execute using this method but only when the site is loaded. If I traverse to other pages, it doesn't, even when I come back to the same page.

### *UPDATE*

For now, I've got it working by keeping the method 4 and copying the entire code from `main.js` in `gatsby-browser.js` under `onRouteUpdate` like so:

```
const $ = require("jquery");

exports.onRouteUpdate = () => {
  $(document).ready(function(){
    // Code
  });
}
```

However, I know this is redundant and definitely not the correct way of doing things.

Comment: you can do one thing like put your script in utility directory and import that file in your component.

Comment: There are some pages which aren't component based and some that are dynamically generated so I can't go ahead with this

Comment: why not? you must have had created template for those dynamic pages where you can import it.

Comment: Even if I could, I'd have to use `react-helmet` which is the same as method 4

Comment: If you're using React, you shouldn't be using jQuery, and you shouldn't be touching the DOM.

Comment: @doublejosh learnt that the hard way :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best and cleanest solution is provided by `gatsby-browser.js`. You could try something like:

```
import yourScript from '../../your/script/path/file.js'

export const onClientEntry= () => yourScript();
```

As you can see in [Gatsby Browswer APIs documentation](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/browser-apis/), Gatsby offers several available and suitable APIs to trigger in (almost) any desired use-case. The one that fits your requirements best is `onClientEntry`. According to the documentation:

> `(_: emptyArg, pluginOptions: pluginOptions) => undefined`
>
> Called when the Gatsby browser runtime first starts.

The script will be triggered on the first render and when navigating through pages using anchors, not using `@reach/router` (`<Link>` and `navigate`).