# Script only works on page refresh in Gatsby/React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

I'm trying to use a script from [Tock](https://www.exploretock.com/) in my Gatsby website which converts a "Reserve" button into a widget.

I have tried many different ways suggested here to make this work including the methods listed in [this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48966464/add-raw-html-with-script-inside-gatsby-react-page)

If I put the script in the component as shown below or in html.js, the code works but only if I refresh the page. If I navigate to the page from another page, it doesn't work.

If I place in an external JS file I get compiling errors.

What I thought should be simple is providing incredibly challenging so any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks

```
class ReserveTock extends React.Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <>
                <script dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
                __html:`
                !function(t,o,c,k){if(!t.tock){var e=t.tock=function(){e.callMethod?
                e.callMethod.apply(e,arguments):e.queue.push(arguments)};t._tock||(t._tock=e),
                e.push=e,e.loaded=!0,e.version='1.0',e.queue=[];var f=o.createElement(c);f.async=!0,
                f.src=k;var g=o.getElementsByTagName(c)[0];g.parentNode.insertBefore(f,g)}}(
                window,document,'script','https://www.exploretock.com/tock.js');
                tock('init', 'websitename');
                `}}
                />

                <a className = {"btn " + this.props.buttonColor + ' ' + this.props.className}
                   href="https://www.exploretock.com/websitename"
                   data-tock-reserve="true"
                   data-tock-experience={this.props.experienceTockId}
                >
                    Reserve
                </a>
            </>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: @ksav unfortunately no, I've updated my question to clarify

Comment: theres a race condition somewhere.  probably not working coming from another "page" cuz it's already loaded and was too early and when it works when you refresh it's cuz you're looking at the component already so it actually has somewhere to go.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience: third party scripts that you load into your page need to go as high up in the HTML as possible. So put the script tag directly in the HTML head, don't inject it with JavaScript :)

Comment: Thanks. If I put it in in <Helmet> like this <script type='text/javascript'>!function(t,o,c,k){if... it gives me "unexpected token" error

Comment: Add `defer=false` in your Helmet? https://github.com/nfl/react-helmet/issues/314

Comment: I actually get errorr reported in my IDE - https://pasteboard.co/ITZE8FW.png