# getting unexpected token error while declaring global variable?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am getting  `**Unexpected token '&'**` error while declaring globle variable .I also tried to stringily it's value but still getting same error why ?

I am doing like this.

```
<Head>
 

   {
      <script type="text/javascript">
        var s_pageName2=JSON.stringify('abc:en-us:/lo-form')
      </script>
    }
  </Head>
```

here is my whole code
https://codesandbox.io/s/long-bird-tgwcv?file=/pages/index.js

Ia m using nextjs framework . I want to create global variable having value this `abc:en-us:/lo-form`

This is not **codesandbox** error .I am facing same issue on my local machine

[image]

Comment: That string isn't valid JSON so you should just get rid of `JSON.stringify`

Comment: I tried without json.stringify .. but still same issue

Comment: @MattU see https://codesandbox.io/s/long-bird-tgwcv?file=/pages/index.js

Comment: any solution remove this error ? https://codesandbox.io/s/long-bird-tgwcv?file=/pages/index.js. see on console

Comment: why you want to do that? 
In react you cannot/ sould not  do that, react just wont work in this way. if you want to use variables in all of your components there are other ways to do that.

Comment: I am using nextjs ..I want to set global variable

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add <script> tag using ReactJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31276926/how-to-add-script-tag-using-reactjs)

Answer (score 0):

In jsx you cannot just do that, you can use  [dangerouslySetInnerHTML](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml), but i highly discourage to use it.

```
<script
  dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
    __html: ` var s_pageName2='abc:en-us:/lo-form'`
  }}
/>
```

If you want to store a global variable to reuse in any of your components there are differents ways for achieve that, for example using react Context and expose a custom hook to use wherever you need to.

Example :

_app.js

```
    import { MyProvider} from '../components/MyProvider'
    
    
    function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
        return (
                <MyProvider>
                    <Component {...pageProps} />
                </MyProvider>
        )
    }

export default MyApp
```

/components/MyProvider :

```
import React, { useState, useEffect,useContext } from 'react'
export const MyContext= React.createContext(null)

export function MyProvider ({ children }) { 
    const [myVar, setMyVar] = useState('abc:en-us:/lo-form')
    return (
        <MyContext.Provider value={{myVar}}>
            {children}
        </MyContext.Provider>
        
        )
 }

export function useApp() {
    const value = useContext(MyContext)
    return value
}
```

Then in any other component / page you can just use your hook in this way :

```
import { useApp } from './components/MyProvider'
const MyPage= () => {
  const {myVar} = useApp()
   ... rest of code

}
```

This is just an example, you can achieve that in many ways, it depends on your app business logic.

Comment: thanks Nico..I was using first method. variable is set . but it give new error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input`

Comment: actually I want to set a variable on window so that other script 3 party script can read that value do the stuff

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/hungry-breeze-frosm this works for me.