# Adding Scripts to head with nextjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, jsx

I would like to implement a script within my next.js app
I'm currently using

```
import Script from "next/script";
```

and then within my

```
return (
<div>
<Script>const tooltips= {color: true, icon: true, size: true}</Script>
<Script src="url to script"></Script>
<main>
</main>
</div>
)
```

the script loads, but how can i set the tooltips const in nextjs?
using

```
const something = ""
```

doesn't work.
I tried using the script within a normal html file and it works. How would i implement this in nextjs?
I'm probably already implementing it wrong because i cant use const after my return?
What would be the right way to set these values?

Comment: you can use `globalThis.tooltips`. Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/globalThis

Comment: Does this answer your question: [How to add <script> tag using ReactJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31276926/how-to-add-script-tag-using-reactjs)? You need to use the `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` prop to set the `scripts`'s code (`next/script` is just a wrapper around the `<script>` element which will forward its prop to it).