# Unable to write JQuery code in Next.js App

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I want to add tracking code in Next.js but its not working.

```
<Script>
          window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
          function gtag(){
            dataLayer.push(arguments)
          }
          gtag('js', new Date());

          gtag('config', 'UA-xxxxxxxxx-1');
        </Script>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question: [How to add <script> tag using ReactJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31276926/how-to-add-script-tag-using-reactjs)? And that's not jQuery, it's regular JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code may work for you.
I put the script in _app.js

```
function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return (
    <>
      <script dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
        __html: `Your script`}}></script>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </>
  );
}

export default MyApp;
```